# Layered keyboard using autohotkey

Tags: windows, keyboard, autohotkey

While making my keyboard layered, I wanted to remove the default behavior of the `,` key. I have already mapped `CapsLock`+`j` to give me `,` input. Now, I want the new behavior of pressing only `,` to be BackSpace and `CapsLock`+`,` to be `}` input. How can I achieve this using AutoHotKey script?

PS: I am trying to achieve the same [keyboard layout](https://medium.com/@jack_21924/crackle-keyboard-layout-for-special-characters-e4dd04838231) for both my Mac and Windows machines. The layout I am trying to achieve is very close but not 100% exact as in the above link.

What I have so far (you can skip over to last 9 lines of code):

```
#SingleInstance Force 
  
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases. 
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors. 
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability. 
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory. 
  
; For easy access of Control Key 
LAlt::Ctrl 
  
; Use Alt as Snap keys 
CapsLock::Alt 
'::Alt 
  
  
`;::Enter 
,::Backspace 
.::Ctrl 
/::Shift 
  
  
!a:: 
Send, ~ 
return 
!s:: 
Send, =  
return 
!d:: 
Send, ‘   
return 
!f:: 
Send, “  
return 
!g:: 
Send, -  
return 
!z:: 
Send, <  
return 
!x:: 
Send, {{} 
return 
!c:: 
Send, [  
return 
!v:: 
Send, (  
return 
!b:: 
Send, /  
return 
  
  
!{:: 
Send, | 
return 
!}:: 
Send, Ctrl  
return 
!h:: 
Send, {+}  
return 
!j:: 
Send, ,  
return 
!k:: 
Send, .  
return 
!l:: 
Send, {Esc} 
return 
; the following will now work currently cause ; has already been mapped to Enter key, find a solution 
!`;:: 
Send, ?  
return 
!n:: 
Send, \  
return 
!m:: 
Send, )  
return 
!,:: 
Send, ] 
return 
!.:: 
Send, {}} 
return 
!/:: 
Send, >  
return
```

Comment: Show what code you have so far.

Comment: What @0x464e said, if you show us what you have already tried, we can better understand your problem and give you a better solution faster.

Comment: I should have done initially. I posted what I have so far.

Comment: @0x464e Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Probably, but I'm not home until Sunday.

Comment: @myaliasname3333 what is supposed to go wrong? The stuff you mentioned seems fine to me. Except you saying `CapsLock` (but actually `Alt`) + `,` should be `}`, but in the code you have it down as `!,::Send, ]`